# how to decrease the size of a image in bx slider to half

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

Am using a WordPress theme which has a bxslider on it So What it does is displays a full width slider. So I would like to decrease the width of a slider to just half of the screen. I can't find the proper solutions and css to control it.

Answer (score 0):

set '.bx-wrapper' to `width: 50%;` (from the full screen width) and `margin: 0 auto;` to get a half width slider and to center it:

```
.bx-wrapper
{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
```

on default, the slider gets the height from the highest child's element unless you set a specific height to the childs - on default, '.bx-wrapper img' set to `max-width: 100%;` so if the total slider's width got smaller then the image will be the same, if you don't want the slider to get smaller height, set '.bx-wrapper img' to `height: 100%;` and `width: auto;`, the edges of the image may get cut if you will not upload appropriate resolution but you will not lose the slider's height:

```
.bx-wrapper img 
{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

full example: http://jsfiddle.net/1mqzb0gx/3/